# AngularJS Tabs Nested Navigation

Tags: angularjs, tabs, navigation, nested

I am doing the migration to AngularJS, I need to create new tabs  dynamically, with dynamic content and inside of this tab I need  nested navigation. Example: Click on menu, open new tab with CustomerList, click on New button, go to Save/Edit view, after save, go back to CustomerList. That behavior should work in each tab, without changing the content of the others.

I already added tabs dynamically, loaded the customers list, went to the view page, but when I open the customer save/edit windows the buttons stop to work. Another problem is, when I change the active tab, all content is refreshing (lost the state).

Tks for helping me

Comment: You'll have to give us more elements than that. What have you done, how (code samples), what errors do you get (console)? Do you need help for fixing bugs or questioning your approach?

Comment: I need a guide. I'm not sure about the best way for to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way works.

```
<li><a ng-click="newTab('Documentation','Documentação')" href>Documentação</a></li>
```

Html

```
 <tabset id="tabsHome" justified="true">
                <tab ng-repeat="workspace in workspaces"
                     heading="{{workspace.name}}"
                     active=workspace.active>
                    <a ng-click="removeTab(workspace)" href=''><i class="fa fa-times"></i>Fechar</a>
                    <div> 
                       <div ng-include="workspace.url"></div>
                    </div> 
                </tab> 
            </tabset>
```

AngularJs

```
app.controller('TabsCtrl', ['$scope', '$compile', function ($scope, $compile) {
$scope.newTab = function (key, label) {
    if (setAllInactive(key) == false) {$scope.workspaces.push({ id: key, name: label, active: true, url: '/' + key + '/' + key + 'List' });}
}

var setAllInactive = function (id) {
    var work = null;
    angular.forEach($scope.workspaces, function (workspace) {
        if (workspace.id == id) { work = workspace; } workspace.active = false;
    });
    if (work != null && $scope.workspaces.indexOf(work) != -1) {$scope.workspaces[$scope.workspaces.indexOf(work)].active = true; return true;}
    return false;
};

$scope.removeTab = function (workspace) {
    $scope.workspaces.splice($scope.workspaces.indexOf(workspace), 1);
}

$scope.workspaces = []; 
}]);
```

Answer (score 2):

The principe of the `ng-view` directive is to delete entirely the tab content and recreate the DOM at each routing.

However, if you still want to keep the state of your tabs, you should store your data in a factory, which is a singleton.

Comment: I guess that Ui.router and NGroute is not for what I need, because I need 30 tabs open in the same time, and with few many states, and I wont save these states (I just want no change these states while I am using another tab). I will try to do that without ui.router and ngroute.